# Custom batch action in Sonata Admin

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I've posted this 3 times already and cannot seem to see the post don't know what I am doing wrong.

I've created my batch action my my admin class as below:

```
namespace ACME\MyBundle\Admin;

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\Admin;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Show\ShowMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ListMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\DatagridMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Validator\ErrorElement;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Route\RouteCollection;

class JournalistProfileAdmin extends Admin
{
  ...........
  ...........
    public function getBatchActions()
{

    $lists = $this->getModelManager()->createQuery('ACME\MyBundle\Entity\ContactList', 'c')->execute();
    $listsArray = array();

    foreach ($lists as $list)
    {
        $listsArray[$list->getId()] = $list->getName();
    }
    $actions = parent::getBatchActions();

    $actions['addToGroup'] = array(
            'label' => $this->trans('action_add_to_group', array(), 'SonataAdminBundle'),
            'ask_confirmation' => true,
            'secondary' => $listsArray,
        );

    return $actions;
}
}
```

Then extended the CRUDController as in the file below:

```
namespace ACME\MyBundle\Controller;

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Controller\CRUDController as Controller;
use Sonata\DoctrineORMAdminBundle\Datagrid\ProxyQuery as ProxyQueryInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;

class JournalistProfileAdminController extends Controller
{
  public function batchActionAddToIsRelevant()
    {
        return true;
    }
    public function batchActionAddToGroup(ProxyQueryInterface $selectedModelQuery)
     {
        ........................
      ...........................
    }
```

When I try to run my batch action, I get *Sonata\AdminBundle\Controller\CRUDController::batchActionAddToGroup method must be created*  error.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you forgot to specify your JournalistProfileAdminController in your service declaration. I just had this problem. The service declaration should look like this (in Services.yml):

```
what.ever.JournalistProfileAdmin:
    class: your\classpath\Admin\JournalistProfileAdmin
    arguments: [ null, your\Bundle\Entity\JournalistProfile, 'YourBundle:Admin\JournalistProfileAdmin' ]
    calls:
        - [...]
    tags:
        - [...]
```

Here the last argument is important. It should not be SonataAdminBundle:CRUD but YourBundle:JournalistProfileAdmin

Your question is pretty old, but I hope this will help someone one day.

Comment: Luckily I had other projects to keep me busy, I can now get this one done with soon. Thanks for the insight

Answer (score 1):

Well, in your second code snippet, you have a batchActionGroup method. This needs to be called batchActionAddToGroup instead (because, in the first code snippet, you are calling your new batch action 'add to group' not 'group').  I hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for pointing the typo. I have duly changed without success